# Creating associations using has_many through with additional attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the 3 models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_recommendations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recommendations, :through => :product_recommendations
end

class Recommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_recommendations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :product_recommendations
end

class ProductRecommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recommendation
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I also have a method which created a new recommendation(s):

```
def self.get_recommendation(product, rating_set)
    r = Recommendation.create
           r.title            =  @title
           r.description      =  @description
           r.cover_img        =  @image_url
           r.curr_price       =  @curr_item_price
           r.save! 
end
```

I am passing in the product object and rating_set attribute when I call the method.

How do I create an product_recommendation association with the 1)The product object. 2) The newly created recommendation object. 3) An additional attribute(rating_set) which belongs to the ProductRecommendation join table.

I tried the following with no luck:

```
product.create_product_recommendations( {:rating_set => rating_set}, {:recommendation => r} ) 
product.recommendations.create( :rating_set => rating_set, :recommendation => r )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by creating the record on the join table as so:

```
pr = ProductRecommendation.new(:rating_set => rating_set.id, :recommendation_id => r.id, :product_id => product.id)
pr.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close...

```
product.product_recommendations.create( {:rating_set => rating_set}, {:recommendation => r} )
```

In the method you mention - the 'create' method will create a new item and put it in the DB. That probably isn't what you want.  Instead, use 'new' and set the params for the new Recommendation like so:

```
r = Recommendation.new(title: @title, description: @description, etc.).
r.save
```

If you are doing this in the controller, you may not need to split it out into a separate method.  Simply call new and save in the controller (create action) - this will allow you to handle errors, redirects, etc.

Comment: For some reason its not adding the recommendation_id. Its saving it as null. This works as expected, however Im not sure how to add the extra rating_set attribute: `code`@product = product
       @recommendation = r
       @product.recommendations << @recommendation